# Problem with Row duplicates when joining dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

> Hi!
>   I have two datasets, lets call them Data1 and Data2. I want to merge these datasets based on individual IDs. My plan is to use following code;

"MergedData <-merge.data.frame(Data1, Data2, by.x="ID", by.y="ID", all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)"

> However, in Data2 there will be duplicates. Data2 is a huge dataset, so there is no use in searching for duplicates before the mergeing (after the merge, if I have done this right, there will only be as many rows as in Data1, but all of the columns from both Data1 and Data2?). 
>   What I want to do is to find out if there is any duplicates in Data2 which will also affect Data1. Thankful for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,3),d=c("car","bike"))
    df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3),b=c(1,1,2,2))
    merge.data.frame(df1,df2,by.x="a", by.y="a", all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
```

your merge keeps duplicates

```
       a    d  b
     1 1  car  1
     2 1  car  1
     3 3  bike 2
```

unique or distinct (tidyverse) will remove them.

Try tidyverse, it's fine if you start with R :)

The tidyverse way :

```
    library(dplyr)
    df1 %>%
        left_join(df2,by="a") %>%
        distinct()
```